# HQL com case, sum e max

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Estou com uma *query* que está dando problema, acredito que o problema ocorra por não permitir utilizar a função `max`, dentro da função `sum`, estou correto?

Como posso contornar isso? Pois preciso somar todos os valores com exceção da última `row`.

Segue a query:

```
"SELECT new project.domain.vo.MediaPagVo(" +
                    "a.nomeUsuario, " +
                    "a.cpfUsuario, " +
                    "a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                    "a.nomeUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                    "a.codigoGrupoUsuario,        " +
                    "a.grupo.id AS idGrupo,         " +
                    "CASE " +
                        "WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN ((MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) > a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                        "ELSE ((MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) >= a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                    "END AS mediaConsumo, " +
                    "CASE " +
                        "WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN " + Tipo.PRE.getValue() + " " +
                        "ELSE " + Tipo.POS.getValue() + " " +
                    "END AS tipoPag) " +
            "FROM " +
                    " Pagamento a " +
            "WHERE " +
                    "a.status = " + StatusPagamento.Concluido.getValue() + " AND " +
                    "a.dataRequisicao BETWEEN :inicio and :fim AND " +
                    "( :idGrupo IS NULL OR a.grupo.id = :idGrupo) " +
                   "GROUP BY " +
                    " a.nomeUsuario, a.cpfUsuario, a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario, a.nomeUnidadeUsuario, a.codigoGrupoUsuario, a.grupo.id, " +
            "HAVING (MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos) > 0 OR MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0) AND " +
                    "( :tipoConsumo IS NULL OR " +
                        ":tipoConsumo = " + Tipo.PRE.getValue() + " AND " +
                        "(MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0) " +
                        "OR :tipoConsumo = " + Tipo.POS.getValue() + " AND " +
                        "(MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos) > 0) ) ";
```

O erro começou a ocorrer depois que eu modifiquei este trecho, acrescentando o `case` dentro do `sum`:

```
"CASE WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN ((MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) > a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                        "ELSE ((MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) >= a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                    "END AS mediaPag, "
```

O erro retornado pelo java:

`Could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00937: não é uma função de grupo de grupo simples`

Meu objetivo era somar todos os pagamentos daquele período, menos o último. Infelizmente, não poderia somente mexer no filtro, pois o `max(a.pre), max(a.pos)` podem ser do último pagamento.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Este erro refere-se ao próprio Oracle:

> ORA-00937: não é uma função de grupo de grupo simples

Em inglês:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function tips

Pelo que entendi, você adicionou os campos `a.dtRequisicao` e `a.valorTotal` dentro daquele SUM. O problema é que eles não estão declarados no `GROUP BY` e (pelo que [entendo do erro](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00937_not_a_single_group_group_function.htm)) que também precisa ser declarados no seu `SELECT`

Sendo assim, a correção seria adicionar eles no `GROUP BY`:

```
"GROUP BY " + " a.nomeUsuario, a.cpfUsuario, a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario, a.nomeUnidadeUsuario, a.codigoGrupoUsuario, a.grupo.id, a.dtRequisicao, a.valorTotal" +
```

E no SELECT:

```
"SELECT new project.domain.vo.MediaPagVo(" +
                "a.nomeUsuario, " +
                "a.cpfUsuario, " +
                "a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                "a.nomeUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                "a.codigoGrupoUsuario,        " +
                "a.grupo.id AS idGrupo,         " +
                "a.dtRequisicao, a.valorTotal,         " +
```

Uma dica: tente não usar [Train Wreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck) no JPQL/HQL, ainda mais repetindo ele em vários locais na mesma consulta. Exemplo: `a.grupo.id`. Muitas vezes o framework JPA cria consultas esquisitas por causa disto e, em alguns casos mais complexos, ocorrem até erros para gerar a consulta SQL. A solução é explicitar o JOIN:

```
JOIN a.grupo grupo
```

E usar `grupo.id`.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas se eu colocar `a.dtRequisicao, a.valorTotal` no `group by`, ele não irá agrupar por esses campos também, afetando o somatório que deveria somar todas os valores independente da data de requisição(com exceção da ultima)?

Comment: @FernandoBittencourt, creio que você precisaria então usar um subselect onde está o case, fazendo um JOIN com algum valor presente no GROUP BY, algo [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526079/2387977). Não consigo dar mais detalhes da solução em si porque precisaria entender todo o contexto da sua consulta (o que seria uma outra dúvida, ao meu ver).

Comment: Optei por refatorar completamente a query, já estava em um nível de complexidade difícil de tratar.

Comment: @FernandoBittencourt, sim, parecia bem complexa mesmo :)